# how can I delete all non-matching query results in django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Say I have a list of values

```
list =['value1',value2'value3'...'...']
```

Is there a way I can run a query against a whole Db and delete any entries that **don't** match?

The opposite of the below almost:

```
models.objects.filter(value__in=list).delete()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [**`.exclude(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude), so:

```
Model.objects.exclude(value__in=list).delete()
```

Comment: Of course - I've been at this for so long my brains turned to mush, you're a star!